# Can you pass a Map into a RemoteAction?

Tags: apex, javascript-remoting

I have an instance where I am trying to pass a dynamic number of Page Parameters into an action method.  It works... but it only will pass as a String.  Is there a way to pass correclty as a Map? (The String version clearly looks like it was meant to be a Map but when passing as a Map I get an error saying that it was passing a String.)

An acceptable alternative would also be an easy way to convert Strings to Maps but I would prefer being able to directly pass a Map.

Comment: The documentation says "collections" are supported which I would interpret to include maps. But maybe the problem is the same one that afflicts @RestResource signatures where maps of objects are not supported. I guess passing the map as a JSON string is a work-around given that Apex has decent JSON support (and of course so does JavaScript).

Comment: @KeithC Hmmmm I might look into doing the JSON version... although I'm already almost done writing the code that will parse a String into a Map.

Comment: A good thing about JSON is that escaping of embedded quotes or line feeds in strings is taken care of.

Comment: JSON is absolutely better than rolling your own parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using JSON to parse it:

```
String jsonPageParams{get; private set;}

...

  jsonPageParams = JSON.serialize(currPageParams);

...

  Map<String, Object> parsedParams = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonPageParams);
```

I had to use a Map of String, Object for some reason even though it's technically a Map.  I just have to cast the result to a String whenever I get the value.

Answer (score -1):

I know this has been answered but I would like to comment anyway.

The way I handled it is by passing Keys and Values as string and recreating the Map in apex.

Here is an excerpt:

So if I were to pass a map through JS, I would send the keys and values as separate JS Array types. Now, note that remoting lets us pass the List(array) of sObject, so the values can be a List `Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.jsRemotingControllerv1.createAccountsMap}', keys, accounts_values);`

Over at the contoller side, I'd recreate the map like this:

```
Map<String,Account> accountMap = new Map<String,Account>();
for (Integer i = 0 ; i < keys.size(); i++) {
    accountMap.put(keys[i],a[i]);
}
```

This example may not be depicting a real lide scenario but it gives an alternative when we no choice but to pass a Map around.

For the complete code, you can see my post here 
https://salesforcemann.wordpress.com/2016/11/16/javascript-remoting-create-account-record-using-single-sobject-list-map/

Comment: link only answers usually get deleted. The contents of your link need shown on your post.

Comment: Oops.. okay will update it soon...